# What nicknames can i use for myself?

Tags: pokemon-go

Its asking me to choose a nickname, ive tried lots but it says this nickname is not availible.

Comment: I don't agree with marking this as a duplicate when the existing question is on hold for being unclear. This question being asked here is very clear, even if it could do with some tidying.

Answer (score 0):

If it says to choose another nickname that means another user has already claimed that name. All you can do is try more names until you find one that isn't being used yet.